# Pass form data onto next page as text

Tags: javascript, forms, cookies

I have an email sign up form generated by our ESP plugged into a webpage.  When the user clicks submit, it takes them to a custom confirmation page we have created.  I would like to display the email address they submitted on the confirmation page, so it says something like, 'Thanks for joining, you will now receive emails at [email address]'.  Our ESP does not provide a way to do this. Is there is a simple way I can grab the email address from the form and pass it to the next page with JavaScript?

I've tried the solutions presented here, but if I try to update the form tag, the form breaks: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?232612-Pass-Variables-from-one-page-to-another-JAVASCRIPT-HTML

I found this article online but I don't understand how the cookie will record only the email address or how to retrieve this information on the next page: http://webdesign.about.com/od/cookies/a/aa083198.htm

Here is the current form code on my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.e2ma.net/app2/audience/tts_signup/1723547/4d1180e592869543e75486faa4eb9d23/37406/?v=a"></script>
<div id="load_check" class="signup_form_message">
    This form needs Javascript to display, which your browser doesn't support. <a href="https://app.e2ma.net/app2/audience/signup/1723547/37406/?v=a"> Sign up here</a> instead 
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">signupFormObj.drawForm();</script>
```

I have very limited understanding of JavaScript and no understanding of PHP so the more specific reply you could give, the better.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Using cookies is probably the easy way to solve this. There are many posts on how to set/read cookies using JavaScript on StackOverflow already.

Comment: Thank you Diodeus, I'll keep researching that route.

Answer (score 0):

since you are submitting a form, hence have access to the email adress on the server side, why don't you just output it?
Javascript looses connection between pages as soon as it unloads. Your attempt to do this with javascript is WAYYYYYY to complicated for something HTML1 was able to do.

Comment: Would this work if my webpages are hosted by different servers than the form data?  I've just plugged code in generated by our ESP, the data is going to their servers.  I found something online about the <output> tag in HTML but it's not supported by IE. Is that what you are referring to?